# integral $\int \frac{1}{sin^{6}x+cos^{6}x} $

Tags: integration

Hi I have checked my working out for numerous times but I could not find any error in it. Could you please have a look at my working out and point out my mistake. Underneath the working out is the correct answer.

[image]

[image: 3]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the post itself is of incredibly low quality. (You know what I’m talking about because you have well over 100 rep.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note

$$\tan^{-1} \frac{\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}
 =\tan^{-1} \frac12\tan 2x 
=\tan^{-1} \frac1{2\cot 2x }\\
= \frac\pi2 - \cot^{-1}  \frac1{2\cot 2x }
= \frac\pi2 - \tan^{-1} (2\cot 2x ) $$

which is equivalent to the answer provided.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int \frac{1}{\sin^6 x+\cos^6 x} dx=\int \frac{4}{4\cos^2 2x+\sin^2 2x} dx=\int \frac{4\sec^2 2x}{4+\tan^2 2x} dx=\int \frac{2}{4+\tan^2 2x} d(\tan 2x)=\arctan{\frac{\tan 2x}{2}}+C $$

Answer (score -1):

For $\tan x,\cot x\ne0,$

$$\cot x-\tan x=\dfrac{1-\tan^2x}{\tan x}=2\cot2x$$

Alternatively,

$$\sin^6x+\cos^6x=(\sin^2x)^3+(\cos^2x)^3=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^3-3\sin^2x\cos^2x(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)$$

$$\dfrac1{\sin^6x+\cos^6x}=\dfrac1{1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x}=\dfrac4{4-3\sin^22x}=\dfrac{4\csc^22x}{4(1+\cot^22x)-3}$$

Now set $\cot2x=y$